# Alterar estrutura de tabela usando JQUERY

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Não sou muito conhecedor de JS, mas preciso resolver um problema usando Jquery.

Estou fazendo uma lista de contatos usando Bootstrap e um plugin chamado Bootstrap-Table que gerencia a questão de filtro e paginação e monta a tabela automáticamente. Mas infelizmente ele usa os cabeçalhos da tabela para populá-la, e meu layout não tem cabeçalhos (TH), pois não é linear. Para eu conseguir fazer o que necessito, pensei em usar o JQUERY para remontar a tabela alterando o código exibido (DOM).

Minha pergunta inicialmente é:

Minha tabela no final tem uma saída como esta:

```
<tbody>
      <tr data-index="0">
          <td class="small" style="">Sector</td>
          <td class="small" style="">Name</td>
          <td class="small" style="">Phone Number</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-index="1">
          <td class="small" style="">Sector</td>
          <td class="small" style="">Name</td>
          <td class="small" style="">Phone Number</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-index="2">
          <td class="small" style="">Sector</td>
          <td class="small" style="">Name</td>
          <td class="small" style="">Phone Number</td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
```

Eu preciso usar o .WRAP() para que tenha uma saída assim:

```
<tbody>
      <tr data-index="0">
          <td class="small" style="">Sector</td>
          <td class="small" style="">Name</td>
</tr>
<tr>
          <td class="small" style="">Phone Number</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-index="1">
          <td class="small" style="">Sector</td>
          <td class="small" style="">Name</td>
</tr>
<tr>
          <td class="small" style="">Phone Number</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-index="2">
          <td class="small" style="">Sector</td>
          <td class="small" style="">Name</td>
</tr>
<tr>
          <td class="small" style="">Phone Number</td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
```

Ou seja , preciso que o SETOR e o NOME fiquem em uma linha e colocar o telefone na pŕoxima.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Aqui, segue minha saída EXATA, com todas as células e linhas que realmente preciso trabalhar:

```
<tbody>
<tr data-index="0">
    <td class="small destaque" style="">SETOR 1</td> <!-- Linha 1-->
    <td class="small destaque" style="">NOME 1</td> <!-- Linha 1-->
    <td style="">RAMAL 1</td> <!-- Linha 2-->
    <td style="">CELULAR 1</td> <!-- Linha 2-->
    <td style="">EMAIL 1</td> <!-- Linha 2-->
    <td style="">TITULO</td> <!-- Linha 3-->
    <td style="">TEXTO 1</td> <!-- Linha 4-->
</tr><tr data-index="1">
    <td class="small destaque" style="">SETOR 2</td> <!-- Linha 1-->
    <td class="small destaque" style="">NOME 2</td> <!-- Linha 1-->
    <td style="">RAMAL 2</td> <!-- Linha 2-->
    <td style="">CELULAR 2</td> <!-- Linha 2-->
    <td style="">EMAIL 2</td> <!-- Linha 2-->
    <td style="">TITULO</td> <!-- Linha 3-->
    <td style="">TEXTO 2</td> <!-- Linha 4-->
</tr>
<tr data-index="2">
    <td class="small destaque" style="">SETOR 3</td> <!-- Linha 1-->
    <td class="small destaque" style="">NOME 3</td> <!-- Linha 1-->
    <td style="">RAMAL 3</td> <!-- Linha 2-->
    <td style="">CELULAR 3</td> <!-- Linha 2-->
    <td style="">EMAIL 3</td> <!-- Linha 2-->
    <td style="">TITULO</td> <!-- Linha 3-->
    <td style="">TEXTO 3</td> <!-- Linha 4-->
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Layout final:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes fazer assim:

```
$('tr').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var last = $this.find('td').last();
    var newTR = $('<tr/>').append(last);
    newTR.insertAfter($this);
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8c1xbpxy/

Explicado seria:

```
$('tr').each(function () {               // iterar todas as linhas
    var $this = $(this);                 // opcional, melhora performance
    var last = $this.find('td').last();  // vai buscar a ultima td de cada linha
    var newTR = $('<tr/>').append(last); // insere ess td numa nova linha
    newTR.insertAfter($this);            // insere a nova linha depois da que está a ser iterada
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta. Atendeu 100% ao que eu perguntei. Na verdade era uma vers]ao simplificada do que tenho. Mas para eu conseguir concluir, acredito que algo deve ser modificado. Atualizei minha pergunta, com o código de saída EXATO. Poderia ver como aplicar o jquery nesta situação ?

Comment: @Leibovich nesse caso acho que é isto que precisas: http://jsfiddle.net/8c1xbpxy/1/ pois, é sempre preferível colocar o código exato. Espero que ajude!

Comment: @Leibovich era isto que procuras? -> http://jsfiddle.net/8c1xbpxy/1/

Comment: Quase isso... Faltou so a linha 3 (e talvez tenha uma 4). Existe como eu usar a classe (CLASS) para definir o numero da linha da td? Pergunto isso pois assim fica facil de adicionar nova. Posso setar para a linha i a class .linha1 para a 2, linha2 e assim por diante.

Se não, qual seria a lógica para eu ter tentro de cada TR 4 linhas (conforme a imagem que coloquei na pergunta)?  

A prósito, @Sergio, muito obrigado pela ajuda. Estou procurando entender melhor o JS mas é como aprender russo..rs.. vai aos poucos

Comment: So deixando mais clara a imagem, o unico texto fixo nela é o "Observações" e depois disso vem outra cell com texto, assim como os anteriores. Então eu teria :
linha 1: Setor e Nome
Linha 2: Ramal , Celular e Email
Linha 3 : Observações 
Linha 4: Texto das observações

Comment: @Leibovich não vejo nenhuma `td` chamada observações... Dá uma olhada aqui: -> http://jsfiddle.net/8c1xbpxy/2/ começo a achar que era melhor fazeres isso quando montas a tabela... podes juntar o código com que montas a tabela?

Comment: Infelizmente minha tabela é criada de forma automática pelo Bootstrap-Table com os dados que vem do Mysql. Mas eu recriei a estrutura e pode ser vista aqui: http://www.bootply.com/vHnJnV9qTI  . Mas se achar que o código de criação ajude mais, posso tentar criar um novo bootply com um arquivo "json" para simular os dados do banco

Comment: @Leibovich e porque não mudar o que vem do MySQL para o JSON já estar certo? se isso não fôr possivel é preferível mudar o JSON que estar a mudar a tabela no DOM.

Comment: é Justamente o que eu faço. Faço uma pesquisa no Mysql e carrego uma  Array e transformo com json_enconde no PHP. Infelizmente o plugin bootstrap table não fornece a possibilidade de uma formatação de tabela não linear, como é a minha. (Ja conversei com os desenvolvedores, e é algo que está sendo estudado para versões futuras.) . Portanto a única maneira de eu conseguir ajustar o meu layout, pelo que eu ocnsegui imaginar, seria ajustar o DOM.  Eu não posso abrir mão do plugin bootstrap-table, pois tenho outras funcionalidades que dependem dele

Comment: @Leibovich ok, boa explicação. E viste então esate meu comentário? -> http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/71462/alterar-estrutura-de-tabela-usando-jquery/71465?noredirect=1#comment147021_71465

Comment: Você atualizou seu exemplo. Falta apenas 1 linha , acima de     TEXTO XXXX , que seria a TITULO (ficando este TITULO como linha 3 e TEXTO XXX como linha 4) . Novamente, obrigado pela paciência e ajuda.

Comment: @Leibovich mas no teu HTML que tens na pergunta não há essa linha certo?

Comment: Estás correto. Não sei por que eu não havia colocado esta linha de Titulo quando postei. Eu atualizei o HTML

Comment: @Leibovich ok, assim já vejo. É assim que procuras? -> http://jsfiddle.net/8c1xbpxy/3/

Comment: Perfeito! é isto mesmo

Answer (score 1):

Explicação do código:

- Procuro o último `<td>`de cada `<tr>`
- Crio um `.clone()` dele
- Removo do `<tr>` o `<td>`
- Crio um novo `<tr>` com meu clone do `<td>`
- Adiciono o novo `<tr>` **DEPOIS** do `<tr>` atual

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#tabelaEspecifica tr').each(function(index) {
      var tdPhone = $(this).find('td:last');
      var novoTd = tdPhone.clone();
      tdPhone.remove();
     
      $(this).after($('<tr/>').append(novoTd));
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="tabelaEspecifica">
  <tbody>
      <tr data-index="0">
          <td class="small" style="">Sector</td>
          <td class="small" style="">Name</td>
          <td class="small" style="">Phone Number</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-index="1">
          <td class="small" style="">Sector</td>
          <td class="small" style="">Name</td>
          <td class="small" style="">Phone Number</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-index="2">
          <td class="small" style="">Sector</td>
          <td class="small" style="">Name</td>
          <td class="small" style="">Phone Number</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta. Atendeu 100% ao que eu perguntei. Na verdade era uma vers]ao simplificada do que tenho. Mas para eu conseguir concluir, acredito que algo deve ser modificado. Atualizei minha pergunta, com o código de saída EXATO. Poderia ver como aplicar o jquery nesta situação ?